# How can I skip the opening logos in Bioshock: Infinite?

Tags: pc, bioshock-infinite

When I start the game, I have to sit through a barrage of unskippable logos and splash screens. How do I disable these logos and get straight to the main menu?

Comment: The information is also available at PC Gamer along with some other useful tweaks - http://www.pcgamer.com/2013/03/27/bioshock-infinite-tweaks-let-you-skip-intro-videos-increase-fov-and-adjust-sensitivity/

Comment: You can click right through all of them but the copyright screen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, open up `XEngine.ini` in your favorite text editor. You'll find this file in your config folder:

`C:\Users\[Your Name]\Documents\My Games\BioShock Infinite\XGame\Config\`

In `XEngine.ini`, scroll down to the `[FullScreenMovie]` section. Look for the following four lines, and disable them by adding a semicolon (`;`) at the beginning of the line:

```
StartupMovies=2KLogoSweep720p2997
StartupMovies=IrrationalLogoTest
StartupMovies=UE3AnimatedLogo_ProRes
StartupMovies=AMDLogo720p
```

Save and close the file. Now when you launch the game, you'll only see the copyright and autosave screens before the main menu. (I haven't yet found a way to disable those)

Comment: you answered your own question immediately after you posted it?

Comment: @Outlier: [Nothing wrong with that](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: oh wow didn't know that. Thanks for the link

Comment: I don't think those folders are correct.  Both Vista and 7 use `C:\Users` - `C:\Documents and Settings` is from XP.  Also, `My Games` is under the `Documents` subdirectory for me.  I assume it's the same in Windows XP?  I've edited the answer, but could someone please double-check that their folders are in the same location?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Correct on both counts. I was doing this from memory and I got it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I just press left click and SPACE bar fast and although they are not as elegant as your solution but still it is fast